# Vectorize over only one axis in a 2D array with numpy vectorize

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization

I have the following function to get the Euclidean distance between two vectors `a` and `b`.

```
def distance_func(a,b):
    distance = np.linalg.norm(b-a)
    return distance
```

Here, I want `a` to be an element of an array of vectors. So I used numpy vectorize to iterate over the array. (In order to get a better speed than iterating with a for loop)

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(distance_func)
```

I used this as follows to get an array of Euclidean distances

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]])
b = np.array([1,2])

vfunc(a,b)
```

But this function returns:

> array([[ 0.,  0.],
>          [ 1.,  1.],
>          [ 2.,  2.],
>          [ 3.,  3.],
>          [ 4.,  4.]])

This is the result of performing the operation `np.linalg.norm(a-b)` individually for the second vector. 
How do I use numpy vectorize to get the array of Euclidean distance in this way?

Comment: From the `vectorize` documentation: `The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute euclidean distances between all of your data points, you should use one of the functions provided to this effect

```
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
```

They are optimized to calculate the distances of several points `a` to *several* point `b` in a fully vectorized manner.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(100, 2)
b = np.random.randn(200, 2)

d1 = euclidean_distances(a, b)
d2 = distance_matrix(a, b, p=2)
print d1.shape  # yields (100, 200), one distance for each possible couple
print d2.shape
```

Speed considerations

```
In [90]: %timeit d1 = euclidean_distances(a, b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 403 us per loop

In [91]: %timeit d2 = distance_matrix(a, b, p=2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 699 us per loop
```

Comment: I doubt that you can get much speed from `sklearn.metrics.euclidean_distances`. I've tried it, but `numpy.linalg.norm` method is somewhat faster than sklearns' method.

Comment: Do you know how to do the exact thing described in the question with `scipy.spacial.distance_matrix`. This version you have given returns distances for each possible couple.

Comment: If you reduce `b` to one vector (e.g. `b = np.array([[0, 1]])`), then, if I understand the question correctly, this should reduce to exactly what you are looking for (distance to `b` for each vector of `a`, right?)

Comment: Yes. This does exactly What I mentioned in the question. And it's faster as well.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `vectorize`, you can just do:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]])
b = np.array([1,2])

np.linalg.norm(a-b, axis=1)
```

which gives:

```
[ 0.          1.41421356  2.82842712  4.24264069  5.65685425]
```

(I assume this is what you want, but if not, please also show the result you expect for your example.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I expect. But this takes the same time as when I iterate over `a` with a for loop and get the np.linalg.norm() for each vector in `a` and `b`. Isn't there any other way to speed this up?

Comment: This is vectorized.  Most of the speedup for numpy comes from working with larger arrays, and, in fact, for very small arrays, numpy can even be a bit slower.  Is this (5x2) the array size you actually want to use?

Comment: No. Actually I want use this on large arrays. Such as (4000x3000).

Comment: @maheshakya: then you will find this approach to be much faster than a python loop.  I won't run the timing tests because you already have an answer you like, but I suspect the `norm` method you first started with would be comparable in speed to the methods suggested by @eikenberg (if norm will work for you generalized problem -- I'm not sure how you want to expand your problem statement of (2x1)*(2x5) to 4000x3000).